# copy formula in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I should copy a formula into another excel sheet, which is part of the same workbook.
I click on the cell of the sheet2 and I type =, then I go to the cell of the sheet1 and I press enter key. here the problem starts: for some reason, the copied formula is not the one I see on the formula bar by clicking on the cell of the sheet1, but a completely different formula

Comment: Have you tried copying the first cell ctrl-c and going to the other sheet and using ctrl-v ? Or, paste.special formula ?

Comment: @solar-mike if I paste the values everything is ok, but I'm interested in pasting the formula. if I try to paste the formula: #### error in the value

Comment: Perhaps the error is caused by the cells the formula is now referencing in the new sheet are empty... Also if you paste the formula in a different position on sheet 2 it will change the cells the formula is looking at unless you have fixed the cells with $ - the difference between C5 and $C$5.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cell containing the formula you want to copy and select the formula from the formula bar and copy it. Now you can paste it anywhere you want to have the same formula.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you asking. What you are doing is referencing the cell so the formula in sheet2 will be `Sheet1!A1` or whatever cell you're pointing to. If you want to actually get the formula then If you are using Excel 2013 or greater you can set the formula in the cell of sheet to `=FORMULATEXT(Sheet1!B1)`

If you want to take it a step further and apply the same formula in the same manner it is applied in Sheet1 then follow these steps.

1. In my example I set `Sheet1!A1` to 45 and `Sheet1!B1` '=COS(A1)' (no quotes) [This is what Sheet1 looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lIP.png)
2. Then I created a name thanks to a [handy trick still available](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1074053-executing-a-concatenated-string-as-a-formula.html). Click on Name Manager under the Formulas Tab and create a New Name called EVALUATE. Set Refers to: `=EVALUATE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),0,-1))`[Name Manager Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TTtA.png)
3. Lastly, I set `Sheet2!A1` to 90 `Sheet2!B1 = FORMULATEXT(Sheet1!B1)`and then `Sheet2!C1` to `=EVALUATE` [Sheet2 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIbUx.png)

[Here's a snippet of the formulas in Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpxBN.png)

The value in `Sheet2!C1` will be COS(90) and not COS(45) as it was in Sheet1. If this is what you were after then I hope I helped and can get some points so that I can stop looking like a noob. Take care.

Comment: Nothing? I posted an amazing answer by the way!

Answer (score -1):

Generally this never happens. Once you try these steps.

Suppose in Sheet 1 you have Formula in Cell A20 = Sum(A2:A15).

1. Go to Sheet 2, Select the desire Cell.
2. Press = sign.
3. Click the Sheet1 Tab.
4. Select A20 Cell and finish with Enter button.

You find the same Formula will be copied from Sheet1 Cell A20 to Sheet2 destination Cell and will look like =Sheet1!A20.

**NB: You are getting Error ####. It means the Width of the Target Cell in Sheet 2 is smaller than Formula Source Cell in Sheet 1. Simply increase the Column Width in Sheet 2.**

*Hope this help you.*